# How to calculate the variance of the GED distribution?

Tags: distributions, variance

The density of the GED distribution is given by

\begin{align}
GED(l;\mu,\beta,\nu)&=\frac{\nu \exp\left[-(\frac{1}{2}) \left|\frac{l-\mu}{\beta \lambda}\right|^\nu \right]} {\lambda 2^{(1+1/\nu)}\beta\Gamma (1/\nu)}
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the gamma function and
\begin{align*}
\lambda&=\left[ 2^{(-2/\nu)}\Gamma(1/\nu) / \Gamma(3/\nu)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}

how to calculate the variance?

Answer (score 1):

I found it at: [Computational Finance of George Levy page appendix I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750657227).

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2cgif7/5]